# search filter to fetch values between two numbers in swift

Tags: swift, search, filter, tableview

I have a datamodel with set of values.The model is as follows:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Empty
struct SearchDataModel: Codable,Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: SearchDataModel, rhs: SearchDataModel) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    let status: Int
    var data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable,Equatable {
    let userID: Int
    let name: String
    let image: String?
  //  let image: JSONNull?
    let userAddress: String?
    let id: Int
    let listingImage: String?
    let listingVideo: String?
    let listingTitle: String
    let listingAddress: String?
    let listingPrice: String?
    let listingType: String
    let listingUse: String
    let listingSqft: String?
    let listingBedsCount, listingBathsCount, listingParkingSpot: Int?
    let listingDescription: String
    let featureListing: Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id"
        case name, image
        case userAddress = "user_address"
        case id
        case listingImage = "listing_image"
        case listingVideo = "listing_video"
        case listingTitle = "listing_title"
        case listingAddress = "listing_address"
        case listingPrice = "listing_price"
        case listingType = "listing_type"
        case listingUse = "listing_use"
        case listingSqft = "listing_sqft"
        case listingBedsCount = "listing_beds_count"
        case listingBathsCount = "listing_baths_count"
        case listingParkingSpot = "listing_parking_spot"
        case listingDescription = "listing_description"
        case featureListing = "feature_listing"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

Now based on the attribute listingprice,i want search and filter the data.The price is entered in the textfield as two values which denotes the starting and ending number.The price falling between these two numbers has to filtered and reload the tableview.

The logic i have used to filter the price is as follows:

```
let price = orgsearchDataModel?.data.filter{$0.listingPrice! > self.minPrice.text! && $0.listingPrice! < self.maxPrice.text!}

 for items in 0..<price.count{
                    self.searchidArray.append(self.searchDataModel!.data[items].id)
                    
                }

 self.alllistcollview?.reloadData()
```

This statement is throwing error as nil.How to filter between two numbers and reload the tableview.

Comment: Your listing price is String, let listingPrice: String?. Are you sure listing price is coming String from Web Service

Comment: You should convert all values to Double or Int before doing the comparison

Comment: @udbhateja yes the client wants it to be string..

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes will try it that way.But is this syntax correct?

Comment: The listingprice from api is a string.How to convert that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert String to Int or Double based on your requirement and then filter the data from the array

```
guard
    let min = Int(minPrice.text ?? "0"),
    let max = Int(maxPrice.text ?? "0") else {
    return
}

let results = data.filter({
    if let price = Int($0.listingPrice ?? "0") {
        return (price > min && price < max)
    }
    return false
})
```

//Assign the result to tableView datasource and reload the tableView.

Comment: i will try this and let u know

Comment: Is it possible to combine with another search filter and show the results?Like i have another search filter let list3 = orgsearchDataModel?.data.filter( { $0.listingType.range(of: type, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}).I want to combine the result from price and this one.basically intersection of both search.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Add one more && condition to satisfy your filter requirements.

Comment: i want intersection of both search filter. 
let a = list1!.filter () { list2!.contains($0) && list3!.contains($0) && list4!.contains($0)}.I wrote it this way.it works fine with list2 and list3.but with list4 filter it is not working.list4 is the result of price search

Comment: A more simple way will be to use Set to store the result of filter and then perform an intersection of these sets. By using sets, logic will be easier t understand and debug.

Comment: how to get set from the search result?it is of type datamodel.

Answer (score 0):

All values needs to be converted to Int or Double, I have assumed it is Double here since this is more normal for a price.

You need to take into account that the list price can be nil but also that the user has not entered both min and max or entered something that isn't a number. An empty max field for instance means we should not filter for a max price.

```
//Convert values given by user, might result in a nil value
let minLimit = Double(minPrice.text!) 
let maxLimit = Double(maxPrice.text!)

//First check that list price is valid and if so ignore this item
//Then if limit is nil approve item or filter agains price for both min and max
let items = data.filter {
    guard let price = Double($0.listingPrice) else { return false }
    return (minLimit == nil || price >= minLimit!) &&
        (maxLimit == nil || price <= maxLimit!)
}
```

Then I don't really understand what you are doing with the result and why you can't use it directly but if you need to do the mapping to `id` then this should do

```
self.searchidArray = items.map(\.id)
```

Comment: i will try this